# Prove that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-1$ given a function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-function

I am trying to solve the following exercise. I have the feeling that it is a very simple one, but I am lost. I do not know where to start, because you do not have an specific function. The exercise says:

> If
>   $$F(x, y, z)=0$$
>   prove that
>   $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-1$$

I would appreciate any help you could offer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed. Thank you very much and sorry for not looking correctly for my question.

Comment: Don't delete it. Keep it so we can duplicate it for future visitors.

Comment: All right, I will keep it then. Thanks again